# How to pass my access and secret keys properly for GlueContext?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a glue notebook from which I am trying to read a specific file from a different AWS account. When I try to run a spark session and read it. The code works perfectly and I get the spark df but when I try to use `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame()` I get an `Access Denied` error.

This is what my code looks like so far. Is it cause I am not passing the AWS session credentials correctly?

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

access_key=''
secret_key=''

spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4") \
            .config("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
            .config("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key) \
            .config("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key) \
            .getOrCreate()

sc = spark
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

dynamicFrame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                connection_type="s3",
                connection_options={"paths": ["s3://test/enterprise_survey.csv"]},
                format="csv",
                format_options={
                    "withHeader": True
                },
            )
```

When I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o458.getDynamicFrame.
: java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: N9EQPCTNJZSSENXP; S3 Extended
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid typing your actual creds in the code itself. Rather use a role that can access your services.

For S3 update the s3 bucket policy in the other account which would allow the job to read the data and also add IAM policy to job's account to read data from S3 in other account.